# D language function call with argument

Tags: sdl, d, sdl-2, derelict3

I am learning D and have mostly experience in C#.  Specifically I am trying to use the [Derelict3 Binding](https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3) to SDL2.  I have been able to get some basic functionality working just fine but I have become stumped on how to create an array argument for a specific call.

The library contains a call

```
SDL_RenderDrawLines(SDL_Renderer*, const(SDL_Point)*, int)  //Derelict3 Binding
```

And I have been unable to correctly form the argument for

```
const(SDL_Point)*
```

The SDL Documentation for this function states that this argument is an array of `SDL_Point`, but I am unclear how to create an appropriate array to pass to this function.

Here is an example of what I have at the moment:

```
void DrawShape(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_Point a = { x:10, y:10};
    SDL_Point b = { x:500, y:500};

    const(SDL_Point[2]) points = [a,b];

    Uint8 q = 255;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,q,q,q,q);
    SDL_RenderDrawLines(renderer,points,1);
}
```

And the compiler complains that I am not passing the correct type of argument for `const(SDL_Point)*` in `points`.

```
Error: function pointer SDL_RenderDrawLines (SDL_Renderer*, const(SDL_Point)*, int)
is not callable using argument types (SDL_Renderer*, const(SDL_Point[2u]), int)
```

I suspect this is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays aren't implicitly castable to pointers in D. Instead, each array (both static and dynamic) has an intrinsic `.ptr` property that is a pointer to its first element.

Change your code to:

```
SDL_RenderDrawLines(renderer,points.ptr,1);
```

Comment: chances are that the int argument is the length of the array so the call will be `SDL_RenderDrawLines(renderer, points.ptr, points.size);`

Comment: Originally I had something along those lines but through my various permutations at attempting to get this to work originally I took that out due to one of my attempts not supporting `.length` but I will put something like that back in, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

given that the call asks for a pointer and length, I feel it is safer to define you own wrapper:

```
SDL_RenderDrawLines(SDL_Renderer* rend, const SDL_Point[] points){
    SDL_RenderDrawLines(rend,points.ptr,points.length);
}
```

(why it isn't defined I don't know, any performance hit from the extra function call is just a `-inline` away from being resolved)

Comment: Pardon my inexperience but I am unfamiliar with how to inline the function.  I take it that you just pass an `-inline` argument to the compiler and it determines when to inline?

I found the following at [D Lang: Functions](http://dlang.org/function.html)

Inline Functions

There is no inline keyword. The compiler makes the decision whether to inline a function or not, analogously to the register keyword no longer being relevant to a compiler's decisions on enregistering variables. (There is no register keyword either.)

Comment: yeah `-inline` is a compiler argument that allows the compiler to inline some functions, this is disabled by default in debug builds for clarity in the debugger

Comment: This will not work as-is. Functions in the current module and imported modules are not part of the same overload set. The callee must be fully-qualified, or the function name should be different. For the purpose of wrapping C libraries with prefixed identifiers, it is customary to use namespaces, or lacking those in OOP-capable languages, a type (eg. "SDL" struct) and static methods, so the call becomes SDL.RenderDrawLines.

Comment: "why it isn't defined I don't know" - because once you start going down this route, for consistency you'll also want to take care of arrays in structures, and in structures returned by functions, and it becomes a slippery slope towards some kind of complete marshaling behemoth.